# Запаковка программы в исполняемый файл exe

Tags: php, windows, cmd, bat, exe

У меня есть cmd скрипт для работы моего php кода из консоли.В этой же папке находится файл конфига и папка с php интерпретатором для, собственно, работы самого скрипта в винде из консоли без установки php на машину.Как мне можно все это добро запаковать в единый exe файл, чтобы его можно было вызывать из консоли с заданием параметров и они бы пересылались на скрипт?

Comment: а в чём, собственно, цель? exe даст куда больший спектр возможностей, а творить такую матрёшку довольно странно

Comment: А есть варианты запуска с цельного exe без таких плясек с бубном?Просто я видел лишь варианты вида php file.php и уже упомянутый мной выше вариант с батником, но там та же система.Есть другие предложения?

Comment: вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. запуск с цельного exe - вам прямая дорога в какую нибудь visual studio или delphi. иначе никак, запустить php скрипт на пк на котором нет php - нельзя. только пляски с бубном будет уже ваша идея. проще написать всё что нужно не на php

Comment: Так в том-то и суть что у меня рядом в папке со скриптом лежит интерпритатор который спокойно запускает этот скрипт.Мне просто нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог скинуть все это 1 файлом клиенту и не пришлось ему ставить и настраивать локальный сервер.Включил экзешник, указал значения, скрипт отработал и положил результаты в определенную папку.Все.

Comment: повторюсь, "вам прямая дорога в какую нибудь visual studio или delphi", там можно сделать то что вам нужно

Comment: Ну есть и средства виртуализации, например Vmware ThinApp. Упакуете все что надо в портэйбл версию и отправляйте, кому хотите.